# compiler error with C++ template says that is not the member of struct

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors, factory

I'm a newer of using C++ template and I got trouble with template compiling.
I want to write a similar factory method with template but compiler error says that **'ip is not the member of _FileWriterInfo'**. I was confused because it has be defined in NetWriterInfo struct but not in FileWriterInfo. And if I cancel the 'ip' member defination, compiler works. Apparently T param of NetWriter may infer to FileWriterInfo struct by mistake. How can I get rid of it? plz help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum WriterFormat
{
    WTYPE_FILE = 0,
    WTYPE_NET = 1
};

typedef struct _FileWriterInfo
{
    std::string name;
    std::string page;
}FileWriterInfo;

typedef struct _NetWriterInfo
{
    std::string name;
    std::string ip;
}NetWriterInfo;

template<typename T>
class Writer
{
public:
    virtual ~Writer() {}
    virtual std::string Write(T info) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class FileWriter : public Writer<T>
{
public:
    std::string Write(T info) override {
        std::cout << "name:" << info.name << "\n";
        std::cout << "page:" << info.page << "\n";
        return info.name;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class NetWriter : public Writer<T>
{
public:
    std::string Write(T info) override {
        std::cout << "name:" << info.name << "\n";
        std::cout << "ip:" << info.ip << "\n";
        return info.name;
    }
};

class Creator
{
    Creator() {};
public:
    template<typename T>
    static Writer<T>* CreateWriter(WriterFormat fmt)
    {
        Writer<T>* p = nullptr;
        if (fmt == WTYPE_FILE)
            p = new FileWriter<T>;
        if (fmt == WTYPE_NET)
            p = new NetWriter<T>;
        return p;
    }
};

void WriteFile()
{
    FileWriterInfo info = { "Hello","100" };
    Writer<FileWriterInfo>* w = Creator::CreateWriter<FileWriterInfo>(WTYPE_FILE);
    w->Write(info);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    WriteFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `FileWriterInfo` has the members `name` and `page`, no `ip`.

Comment: Maybe, you try to print the value of member `ip` without checking the type of the template. So the compiler tries to substitute `FileWriterInfo` in the template type and fails.

Comment: The problem is with line `p = new NetWriter<T>;` when `T == FileWriterInfo` it will create the classes out of the class templates and that results in the compile time error.

Comment: @mch actually I want to call the FileWriter method with FileWriterInfo struct param, but it seems to infer to the NetWriterInfo.

Comment: Reopened. I didn't think the duplicate was a good answer to this question (which is quite subtle).

Comment: identifiers starting with underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved. You should not use them

Comment: `typedef struct _FileWriterInfo {/*...*/} FileWriterInfo;` is also not how to do it in C++. This has no benefits (if at all maybe some problems in edge cases) over just `struct FileWriterInfo {/*...*/};`. The `typedef struct` construct is used in C, not C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CreateWriter` function instantiates the `FileWriter` and `NetWriter` classes with the `FileWriterInfo` structure. Accordingly, the compiler tries to instantiate the `NetWriter::Write` function with the type `FileWriterInfo`, and we get an error.

You can place `Write` methods directly to `FileWriterInfo` and `NetWriterInfo` stuctures (according to the principle of data encapsulation). It also can simplify the code.

Comment: how can i modify code if I want to use T with different XXXWriterInfo and got the compile works.

Comment: Can we refactor your code, or need keep this classes structure?

Comment: please refactor freely, and I think that I know how to make it works without using template but passing `void*` param and `static_cast` it to the right struct. But I still want to know how to fix the problem.

Comment: I placed `Write` directly on the structures to be output. Thus, we no longer need the `FileWriter` and `NetWriter` classes, and we managed to simplify the `CreateWriter` method. https://pastebin.com/M2ftiGkS

Comment: I never thought about that. thx for your help!

Comment: @NickWuzh: I think part of your confusion might be because C++ is a compiled language. The `if (fmt == WTYPE_NET)` check happens at runtime, after everything including `NetWriter<T>` is compiled. In script languages, code that is not executed is generally not even checked for errors, but that's a side effect of how those interpreters work.

Comment: @MSalters I thought that compiler can auto infer `T == NetWriterInfo`  in `NetWriter<T>` but actually not. so I'm confused if the compiler infer 'T == FileWriter' at first and it cannot infer to another class

Comment: @NickWuzh: The search term you're looking for is "deduce" - compilers can sometimes deduce template parameters. For function templates, the compiler can deduce the template parameters from function arguments. For class templates, the compiler can deduce them from the constructor arguments. But the compiler won't deduce parameters that you explicitly prvide, as in `CreateWriter<FileWriterInfo>`.